# Xpath in current view with inherit_id

Tags: xpath, odoo, qweb, odoo-12

I'm using Odoo V12 CE and my issue is I try to edit a PageA view.

Have some PageA, PageB and more, inherit ParentPage.

I want to inherit ParentPage into PageA to add some content and, PageB must be: `PageB = ParentPage(without modifications from PageA) + PageB`.

Helps please and thanks for all!!

```
<template id="tpml_id" inherit_id="parent.tpml_parent_id" name="Posts">
    <xpath expr="//ul[@id='post-list']" position="after">
      <span>This is my posts list for all page (MyPage and all page inherits ParentPage). It's so bad. </span>
    </xpath>
  </template>

<!-- I want this -->

<template id="tpml_id" copy_inherit_id="parent.tpml_parent_id" name="Posts">
    <xpath expr="//ul[@id='post-list']" position="after">
      <span>This is my post list for this page only. </span>
    </xpath>
  </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inherit view but do not want to add anything in parent.tpml_parent_id then you can write as following :

```
<template id="tpml_id" inherit_id="parent.tpml_parent_id" name="Posts" primary="True">
    <xpath expr="//ul[@id='post-list']" position="after">
      <span>This is my post list for this page only. </span>
    </xpath>
  </template>
```

Comment: Thanks Mital Vaghani, i will try it !